# Is it possible to change the style using css only but not using any pseudo classes?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
    <li>number 1</li>
    <li>number 2</li>
    <li>number 3</li>
    <li>number 4</li>
    <li>number 5</li>
    <li>number 6</li>
    <li>number 7</li>
    <li>number 8</li>
    <li>number 9</li>
    <li>number n</li>
</ul>
```

This is my html and I don't know how many **`li`** are there.

Now I want to give style to the very first and very last **`li`** but **without using any pseudo class** like first-child last-child last-type-of etc.
And I don't want to use any html attribute nor class as well as **no javascript or jquery**.

Is it possible just using css?

Comment: You could add a "first" class to the first `<li>` in your HTML and do the same for the last one manually if that's an option? Otherwise, using only CSS and without using `nth-child` and similar psuedo classes, I don't think it's possible

Comment: Simply... **NO**.

Comment: Is there a specific need to avoid pseudo classes or JS?

Comment: "Is it possible just using css?" what do you mean? pseudo-classes _are_ "just css".

Comment: This was asked me in interview and interviewer said there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without pseudo class, class nor javascript **there is no way**.

To give content to this answer and for the fun , here is a funny trick to give different colors to the first and last li . but do not try to use this in real. it breaks and mix-blend-mode needs to be supported.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
}

li {
  color: green;
  background: white;
  /*only for tricking last li color*/
  mix-blend-mode: screen/*only for tricking last li color*/
}

li+li {
  /* first one is skipped */
  color: black;
}

ul {
  /*only for tricking last li color*/
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to top, red 1.25em, transparent 1.4em), 
  /* extra fun */linear-gradient( to bottom, black 6em, gray 6em, gray 7.3em, black 7.3em);
  ;
}

.disclaimer {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>number 1 GREEN</li>
  <li>number 2</li>
  <li>number 3</li>
  <li>number n RED</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>number 1</li>
  <li>number 2</li>
  <li>number 3</li>
  <li>number 4</li>
  <li>number 5</li>
  <li>number 6 <strong class=disclaimer>Mix-blend-mode not supported here !</strong></li>
  <li>number 7</li>
  <li>number 8</li>
  <li>number 9</li>
  <li>number n</li>
</ul>
```

[image: fake pseudo class styling]

[Pen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PKMVME)

---

flex can help to fake it, but the last will not be the last

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style-position:inside;
}

li {
  color: green;
  background:yellow;
}

li+li {
  color: crimson;
  order: 2;
}

li+li+li {
  order: 1;
  color: blue;
  background:lightgray;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: counter(li);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wrGLPw